# Get username on OAuth Earth Engine authentication

Tags: google-earth-engine, authentication

I'm using the following code to authenticate users in a web application based on **Google Earth Engine**:

```
var onImmediateFailed = function () {
    $('.g-sign-in').removeClass('hidden');
    $('.output').text('Please log in to use the app.');
    $('.g-sign-in .button').click(function () {
        ee.data.authenticateViaPopup(function () {
            // If the login succeeds, hide the login button and run the analysis.
            $('.g-sign-in').addClass('hidden');
            loadMap();
        });
    });
};

// Attempt to authenticate using existing credentials.
ee.data.authenticate(CLIENT_ID, loadMap, null, null, onImmediateFailed);
```

It works perfectly but I'm not able to get the **username of the authenticated user**.

How can I get it?

Comment: You probably can't, but I'm not sure. At least on desktop, the authentication process uses a key produced in my browser after logging in. I.e. the authentication process never "knows" the user ID, just the authentication key. Not sure how it is for your web app.

Comment: @Jon I've seen that in this app earthmap.org they are able to get the user info, maybe using this: https://developers.google.com/identity/toolkit/web/reference/relyingparty/getAccountInfo